# OCMOD Implementation OpenCart 2.0

Tags: opencart

Have anybody have implemented OCMOD for plugin development in opencart 2.0 ?
Do we need to install VQMOD to execute OCMOD?

I found https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System but still
unable to get clear idea.

Any help would be really appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Refer to following link https://isenselabs.com/posts/opencart-2x-modification-system

Comment: Have anybody have implemented OCMOD for plugin development in opencart 2.0 ? Do we need to install VQMOD to execute OCMOD?

Answer (score 12):

No, You need not to install VQMOD to execute OCMOD. OCMOD works independently.

You have to create ocmod xml file with "**.ocmod.xml**" extension, then you can upload that file using "Extension Installer" from admin panel of opencart.

You have to clear and refresh the modification cache to update the system and make the extension work. 
You can clear and refresh by top right buttons on **Extension > Modification** page in admin panel.

Comment: I've downloaded OCMOD from https://www.opencart.com link and then try to install it from extension installer but it gives me Invalid file type! Any idea why this giving me such error??

Answer (score 6):

OCMod is essentially a poor mans VQMod. there are a number of features missing that aren't/won't be in it that are in VQMod, the biggest of which is being able to add content before/after a certain line match and as such would really recommend just sticking with VQMod which works just fine (version 2.5 and above)

Comment: According to the [OCMod documentation](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) it can add content *before* and *after*...

Comment: @shadyyx - Yes, immediately before and after content, not on a new line before/after without having to match the whole line perfectly. There are other features like index/offset that do nothing or don't work in the same way

Answer (score 4):

I've used ocmod and released a few free oc extensions.
VQMOD and OCMOD are two separate things (as already commented).
Both will not interfere with each other.
You can load ocmod .ocmod.xml scripts from the administration panel (extensions and modifications).

---

A suggestion is to not invest too much work right now since ocmod is still a bit *limited* and probably is going to change in the near future.

A few persons are suggesting to implement quite all the functionalities of vqmod and the whole system/methods can change in the near future
https://github.com/opencart/opencart/issues/2045

I personally prefer vqmod since the development can be faster and you can edit the xml on the fly and refresh the browser. 
I've done 3 different vqmods in around one hour while in ocmod i've spent the same time only to upload/edit/remove the (3) modifications with different tags (required by ocmod).

Caching in ocmod seems to be slower on my system (with a modification on a lot of of php files) and sometimes the modifications are not appearing (in the browser) immediately. I don't know if it's a problem on my specific system.

The logs of ocmod are not giving too much informations in case of errors.

Comment: I've had conflicts when using OCMOD and VQMOD at the same time - was about a year ago... I remember having to convert the OCMOD to a VQMOD to prevent errors

Comment: vqmod 2.6.1 supports ocmod so you could use .ocmod.xml files via vqmod.
For sure sometimes the scripts are not fully compatible (ex. I found ocmod scripts with index="0" that need to be changed to index="1", etc).

They do not "conflict" if you follow the logic of the changes that are done by those two different modification "engines".
The most problematic thing that I found is that OCmod often needs to reload everything from the admin panel (update the cache?).

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get an OCMOD installed today on version 2.0.1.0 of OpenCart.
Did not figure it out and the forums and documentation did not provide adequate help.

While the install may be broken or my environment is bugging it, VQMODs and OCMODs are separate entities and don't depend on one another.

For example, VQMOD uses XML files to store the modifications, and builds a cache with the modified core files.
OCMOD stores the code changes in the database directly without saving the uploaded XML, and seems to build a cache from there (I hope it does the cache part, haven't found proof yet).

The install code for the OCMOD is found in \admin\controller\extension\installer.php

```
public function xml() {
```

So you don't need to mess with VQMOD to get OCMOD working unless you have old VQMODs and don't want to reupload them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried **OCMOD** now, it's pretty easy if you know what files you need to change and how you want to change them. You can find some official documentation [here](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) and a good regexp tester [here](https://regex101.com/).

If you click `Extensions` / `Modifications` / `Add` in admin you can just paste your XML, select `Activated`, `Save` and then `Update` modifications, then click `Log` to check log messages, then check your modified files below the directory `system/modifications`.

Something to remember is to delete your modification and add it as a new one when changing it, it seems that just updating it isn't enough to reload it's XML.

Here is an example module I made to remove wish-list buttons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Remove wishlist buttons</name>
    <code>cjohanssonremovewishlistbutons</code>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <author>Christian Johansson</author>
    <link></link>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl">
        <operation>
        <search trim="true">
            <![CDATA[<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-default" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><i style="color:<?php echo html_entity_decode($config->get('ekometcss_css_wishlist_color'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>;" <i class="<?php global $config; echo $config->get('ekometcss_custom_icons_wishlist') ?  'fa fa-' . $config->get('ekometcss_custom_icons_wishlist') : 'fa fa-star'; ?>"></i></button>]]>
        </search>
        <add position="replace">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/*.tpl">
        <operation>
        <search trim="true">
            <![CDATA[<button style="width: 80%;" type="button" class="cat-cart"]]>
        </search>
        <add position="replace">
            <![CDATA[<button style="width: 100%;" type="button" class="cat-cart"]]>
        </add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
        <search trim="true">
            <![CDATA[<button style="width: 20%;" type="button" class="cat-wishlist" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i style="color:<?php echo html_entity_decode($config->get('ekometcss_css_wishlist_color'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>;" <i class="<?php global $config; echo $config->get('ekometcss_custom_icons_wishlist') ?  'fa fa-' . $config->get('ekometcss_custom_icons_wishlist') : 'fa fa-star'; ?>"></i></button>]]>
        </search>
        <add position="replace">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/category.tpl">
        <operation>
        <search trim="true">
            <![CDATA[<button style="width: 80%;" type="button" class="cat-cart"]]>
        </search>
        <add position="replace">
            <![CDATA[<button style="width: 100%;" type="button" class="cat-cart"]]>
        </add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
        <search trim="true">
            <![CDATA[<button style="width: 20%;" type="button" class="cat-wishlist" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i style="color:<?php echo html_entity_decode($config->get('ekometcss_css_wishlist_color'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>;" <i class="<?php global $config; echo $config->get('ekometcss_custom_icons_wishlist') ?  'fa fa-' . $config->get('ekometcss_custom_icons_wishlist') : 'fa fa-star'; ?>"></i></button>]]>
        </search>
        <add position="replace">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have anybody have implemented OCMOD for plugin development in opencart 2.0 ?

Ans: Yes

Do we need to install VQMOD to execute OCMOD?

Ans: No

OCMOD Folder structure like this for Opencart

```
-upload -admin...(if you have required)
        -catalog..(if you have required)
        - - - - 
- install.xml
```

Zip these and named like this .ocmod.zip

Then You can able to install with Opencart Installer

Answer (score 0):

No
VQMOD is seperated Plugin that depend on file system XML Files
OCMOD Depend on DB when you install new  ocmod plugin it stored in modifications table